# (MVC C#)Advice on my Maintenance Scheduling system with Maintenance Records

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have this maintenance scheduling system, and in im using MVC C# Entity Framework,

I have this table
Truck Table that has - truck id, registration no., kilometer run reading, and i have an JobOrder Table, i want to get the truck id in the truck table so that i can add a JobOrder on a specific Truck i have this JobOrder Controller

```
public ActionResult AddJobOrder(JobOrderModel jo, int id)
{
    var AddJobOrder = db.trucks.FirstOrDefault(s => s.id == id);

    var addjo = new joborder()
        {
            truck_no = AddJobOrder,
            description = jo.Description,
            worked_performed = jo.worked_performed,
            quantity = jo.Quantity,
            spare_parts = jo.SpareParts,
            run = jo.kilometer_run,
            date_finished = jo.DateFinished,
            date_started = jo.DateFinished,
        };

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.joborders.Add(addjo);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return View(jo);

    }
    return View(jo);

}
```

I receive the following error:

> Error 4   Cannot implicitly convert type 'Pms_system.truck' to 'int'

This is my model

```
public class JobOrderModel
{
    public int truck_no { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateStarted { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateFinished { get; set; }
    public string SpareParts { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int kilometer_run { get; set; }
    public string worked_performed { get; set; }

}
```

Please help me to get the truck id.

Comment: So which line is the error on? If it's `var AddJobOrder = db.trucks.FirstOrDefault(s => s.id == id)` we'll need to know more about `db.trucks`. (I'd also *strongly* advise you to start following .NET naming conventions.)

Comment: truck_no = AddJobOrder, this is the error

db.trucks has an Id as an primary key

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is just a matter of getting the ID out of the truck - after all, your oddly-named `AddJobOrder` variable is presumably of type `Truck` or something similar. I suspect you just need something like:

```
truck_no = AddJobOrder.id,
```

After all, that's how you're getting at the truck ID in the query just beforehand. It's not entirely clear why you need the query at all if you *only* need the truck ID, which has been provided to the method anyway - all you're doing at the moment is allowing you to check whether or not there *is* such a record, although you should then actually *do* the check by seeing whether `FirstOrDefault` returned `null`.

I would also *strongly* advise you to take a good look at the names you're using, both in terms of capitalization and semantic names too. (Your `AddJobOrder` variable should be called `truck` or something similar by the sounds of it. The fact that it's the same name as the method is doubly confusing!)